# How to handle filtering in restlet resource

Tags: java, android, server, restlet

Hi i am pretty new to Restlet, and generally building web servers. I need to support filtering like this:
http://deviceip:port/resource?id=id

So far i know how to return a json message when user invokes different resources, based on my web server state. I would attach it to router, and add class which handles that resource. But how can i return only one resource from collection based on id? What i need to change in my class which is responsible from handling of that resource. Also how can i attach this resource to router? Any help is welcome, if you can write some code snippet to help me, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as i understand you can approach to this in two ways. One is explained by link above and another one is using query. So basically you font have to create another resource like in the answer from link above, instead you can just extract query with `this.getQuery()` 
and than call method `getFirstValue("id")`, which will return entered id.